# How to pass variables from Jquery to the view in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

After struggling many hours finding a solution to pass some variables from the view to the jquery code, now I have to do it vice-versa.

Is there any solution to this?

My scenario:

- 2 values entered in a form.
- Values are sent to my API using Jquery in my view in rails.
- Data is back from my API
- I want to publish this data in the front-end.

Any idea? Thxs in advance.

Comment: you can assign jquery value to input fiels using jquery `.val()` methods

Comment: This totally depends on how you want to display the data, and there are like a billion ways to skin a cat. But basically you would create a callback on ajax success which creates some HTML and appends it to the DOM. Just search for "jQuery ajax"; there are tons of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Use data-attributes

```
<div id='info' data-info='<%= @varialble.id %>'>
$('#info').data('info') in your js code
```

Comment: It seems a good idea, but its not clear the example for me. I am newbie to jquery. Is it possible that you explain it for me?

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem is that Im doing an AJAX called and outside $.ajax({....}); it is not possible to get the data gotten in AJAX.